# How to generate the new HTML Page based on user link click in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just give me a hint how i start to display the user profile using a id in anchor click.

My homepage URL is `localhost/CRM/dashobard.html`. Also i have complete JSON in which i have already fetched all Lead details and i am displaying some of its content in columns via a table in the file `dashboard.html`

[image]

Also in `dashboard.html` file i am using PHP sessions as below.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['State'] == 'Authenticated'){

     $user_id = $_SESSION['User_Id'];

     if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
     {

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
     }   

     $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");     

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <html lang="en">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Dashboard</title>

         </head>
<body>

all header and sections tag  content are there

</body>
</html>
<?php 

    }else{    

        echo "<script>location.href='https://localhost/CRM/login.html';</script>";    

    }


    ?>
```

and i want to display the user profile in `localhost/CRM/dashboard.html/17/John-doe` or `localhost/CRM/dashboard.html/lead/17/`

I have table with `Lead Name` in column values. I want to allow user to click on the `Lead Name` and a separate page is displayed to user with all other details apart from the other columns which are not there in table, in a new tab and this may be done by dynamically making profile page but as i don't know which `Lead Name` is clicked by the visiting user. I think i am lacking the concept of URL forwarding.

Below is screenshot of Front end.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am generating the above table dynamically using AJAX and table has row with anchor tag `Lead Name` where user can click and access to profile page. but i think this need to generate dynamically HTML page but i don't know how to do it.

For example, In below code file `loadtable.js`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 1000;

    // Campaign Submit Info
    $('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
        var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
        var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
        var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
        var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
        var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
        var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
        var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
        var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
        var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",            
            url: "./server/search.php",
            data: {
                "lead_status": lead_status,
                "campaign_status": campaign_status,
                "company_name": company_name,
                "tech_area": tech_area,
                "firm_size": firm_size,
                "firm_type": firm_type,
                "country_name": country_name,
                "state_name": state_name,
                "start_date": start_date,
                "end_date": end_date
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.message_box').html(
                    '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                );
            },

            success:function(data){

                var result = $.parseJSON(data);

                console.log(result);

                $("#filterRecords").empty();

                var table='';

                table = $("<table></table>");

                table.append('<thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Lead Owner</th><th>Details</th></thead>'); 

                table.append('<tbody></tbody>'); 

                var i = 1;

                $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                    table.last().append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td><a target='_blank' class='lead-name' href="+value['Lead_Id']+">" + value['FirstName'] + ' ' + value['LastName'] + "</a></td><td>" + value['Company'] + "</td><td><a href=mailto:" + value['Email'] + ">" + value['Email'] + "</a></td><td>" + value['Phone'] + "</td><td><a target='_blank' class='lead-owner' href=" + value['LeadAddedBy'] +">" + value['LeadAddedBy'] + "</td><td>" + "<form action='' method='POST'><button id=" + value['Lead_Id'] + " name=''>View</button></form>"+"</td></tr>");

                    i = i + 1;                

                });

                $("#filterRecords").html(table);
                $('.message_box').html('');
            }           

        });

    });

});
```

In PHP file which run SQL query and return JSON object.

```
<?php 

// send a JSON encoded array to client

include('connection.php');

$selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info ";

$result_array = array();

$result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

// If there are results from database push to result array

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        array_push($result_array, $row);

    }

}

echo json_encode($result_array);

$conn->close();


?>
```

In the file where table are displayed `dashboard.html`

```
<!-- Filter section with Main Lead Table  -->
<section class="operation" id="view_lead_info" style="display: block;">

<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
                        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                           <div id="filterRecords"></div> 
                        </div>                        
                    </div>                    
                </div> 

</section>
```

SQL for table used for displaying profile.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_main_lead_info`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_main_lead_info`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_main_lead_info` (
  `Lead_Id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Website` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Designation` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Linkedin` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TechArea` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirmType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirmSize` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastContactDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `NextContactDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeadDescription` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OwnerNotes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SetReminder` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdminNotes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeadStatus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeadAddedBy` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `LeadAddedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Lead_Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FirstName` (`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Company`,`Website`,`Designation`,`Linkedin`,`Email`,`Phone`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_main_lead_info`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_main_lead_info` (`Lead_Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Company`, `Website`, `Designation`, `Linkedin`, `Email`, `Phone`, `State`, `Country`, `TechArea`, `FirmType`, `FirmSize`, `LastContactDate`, `NextContactDate`, `LeadDescription`, `OwnerNotes`, `SetReminder`, `AdminNotes`, `LeadStatus`, `LeadAddedBy`, `LeadAddedOn`) VALUES
(18, 'Tohn', 'Doe', 'Microsoft', 'www.microsoft.com', 'Manager', 'Tohn Doe', 'tohndoe@microsoft.com', '5125501556', 'California', 'USA', 'Wireless technologies', 'Corporate', '1000+', '2020-01-27', '2020-01-31', 'This is a testing description', NULL, '2020-02-27', 'This is Admin Notes Testing', 'Active', 18, '2020-01-15 10:50:36'),
(17, 'John', 'Doe', 'Google', 'www.google.com', 'Manager', 'John Doe', 'johndoe@google.com', '5125501555', 'Texas', 'USA', 'Intellectual Property', 'Corporate', '11-50', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-25', 'This is a Testing Description', 'This is My Notes Belongs to Rinku 16', '2020-01-17', NULL, 'Active', 22, '2020-01-14 17:04:02');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically create a page from some data you'd need PHP. Let's say your page is something like this:

show-profile.php

```
$lead_id = $_GET[ 'lead_id' ]; // Get the lead_id value, of course you'd need to check if it has been set, is valid, etc.

... here your code to retrieve info through the $lead_id value ...
```

In your table it will be enough to put a link like this one:

```
"<a target='_blank' href='show-profile.php/?lead_id=" + value['Lead_Id'] + "'>Show Details</a>"
```

**Edit**

Here's a more detailes example of the show-profile.php page:

```
<?php
  if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'lead_id' ] ) {
    echo( 'No parameter lead_id given' );
    exit;
  }

  $lead_id = $_GET[ 'lead_id' ];

  $data = get_details( $lead_id );

  # Here you can check about the $data returned, which depends by your get_details function, to check if the details has been found or not and act consequently. Here we suppose you got the right data to make it short.

?>

<!-- HTML page definition, HTML, HEAD, LINKS, etc. goes here -->

<body>
  <div id="details">
    <p class="first-name">First Name: <?php echo $data[ 'first_name' ] ?></p>
    <p class="last-name">Last Name: <?php echo $data[ 'last_name' ] ?></p>
    <!-- other data to show here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

In the code, of course, get_details is your function to retrieve the data through the $lead_id value.

**Edit 2: with JSON data already got**

Let's say your data to show are present in a JSON object:

```
data = {
  lead_id: 20,
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
}
```

your link to open the details page will look something like this:

```
"<a target='_blank' href='show-profile.php/?lead_id=" + data.lead_id + "&first_name=" + data.first_name + "&last_name=" + data.last_name +  "'>Show Details</a>"
```

And your show-profile.php page will look something lihe this:

```
<?php
  # Check if all the data you need has been given
  ... your code ..

  # Retrieve the data and store them into variables
  $lead_id = $_GET[ 'lead_id' ];
  $first_name = $_GET[ 'first_name' ];
  $last_name = $_GET[ 'last_name' ]; 
?>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>  
    <p class="first-name">First Name: <?php echo $first_name; ?></p>
    <p class="last-name">Last Name: <?php echo $last_name; ?></p>
    <!-- other data to show here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so html text to display profile information is in `show-profile.php`

Comment: Exactly, there you'll first get the data through the $leadid value, let's say you'll get those data inside an array and then, on the page you'll put some html to render the data from the array. Does it makes sense?

Comment: yes your saying `, on the page you'll put some html to render the data` means that i can use the same `dashboard.html` file and make some div tag there and display the fetched information without changing the URL.  am i right.

Comment: You have to name that page as php file as you'll need some PHP to handle the data display, just edited my answer and added an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: what if i already have that details in JSON, as i am previously using that JSON to display dynamically table.

Comment: Just updated with JSON, you should now have all you need to start.

Comment: Now there is problem of making a new `show-profile.php` because in my `dashboard.html` i am checking for login Session which i saved while login page and when URL move to `localhost/CRM/show-profile.php/..` from `localhost/CRM/dashboard.html` all login session variable are lost.

Comment: See this `if($_SESSION['State'] == 'Authenticated'){` in updated question

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a profile page first where you load the details for a specific profile.

You need to pass the `id` of the record as a query string with your URL like: `www.your-domain.com/?profileId=xxx`

In the profile page, you need to retrieve the `profileId` and make a get request to get the specific profile record from you data store and fill your labels dynamically.

Comment: Thanks but how the URL is changed in case of link click because using link click and ajax function i get the id of the lead (row) but still the URL be like `localhost/CRM/dashboard.html`

Comment: -- you need to create a page first like profile.html

<a target='_blank' class='lead-name' href="/profile.html/?leadId=value['Lead_Id']+">" + value['FirstName'] + ' ' + value['LastName'] + "</a>

Comment: what you want to say for this @Shervin

Comment: Just wondering how you'll retrive data through the leadId argument if you're not using PHP?

Comment: Yes i am using PHP

Comment: Ah perfect then, as @RINKS said, you need to create a php page like show.profile.php which reads the leadId parameter and shows the data. I'm going to give you and example in an answer below.

Comment: with PHP or JavaScript you can access your URL

Answer (score 1):

• The first option is to make a div appear like a window. If you already have fetched all the data, by the element index clicked find the corresponding data in the array and put them to a new template so you can show them.
• Otherwise based on the generated URL in the -a- tag, which should be something like ***example.com?client=2***, you have to make a query, fetch the client details and either in front or the back end make a template out of them.

You could check this out too [How to get parameters from a URL string in PHP?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php/)

Comment: Yes i have JSON in which i have already fetched all Lead details and i am displaying  some of its content in the file `dashboard.html`

Comment: You could save a request and load the data from the the javascript. You could even pass the data as a url parameter with let x = JSON.stringify(data).
Then you could use btoa(x) - this is base64 encoding so you can short it down a bit and then when you pass it through the url atob(JSON.parse(urlParameter)) so you can use them again.
btoa-atob - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: $(element).click(function(){
    let index = $(element).index(this));
    let row = fetchedData[index];
});
This will work if you render them by the order of the array